# Flex Mobile - Simple catalogue . iOS

Tags: ios, flash-builder, flex-mobile

just new in mobile development.
I am starting to use/learn Flash Builder 4.6 and try to do my first test app for iOS

I would like to create a simple app which works like a simple catalogue. Basically a list of images that can be showed and switch between images just moving the fingers. Move from left to right will show next image, move from right to left will show previous image.

Basically the same way that you can see your pictures on your Iphone / Ipad

Do I need to create a view per image?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Flex mobile demo app may overlap your example.

- [Demo application from Finnkino Movies](http://ptm.fi/?p=350)
- [Source Code (FXP)](http://ptm.fi/projects/tabMovies/Movies.fxp)
- [Source Code (ZIP)](http://ptm.fi/projects/tabMovies/Movies.zip)

> [image: movies-0]
>
> [image: movies-1]
>
> [image: movies-2]

You may also want to create a Flex mobile app in Flash Builder using a default template to experiment with transitions of `ViewNavigator`.

References:

- [Demo application from Finnkino Movies](http://ptm.fi/?p=350)
- [Define views in a mobile application](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/mobileapps/WSa122979b4619725672e48c412a3e152164-7fff.html)
- [Define transitions in a mobile application](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/mobileapps/WS8b1c39bd7e9fc36459dd44a012cbc814595-8000.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll have a look. It has been very useful, I have clicked on acept answer, is there any other thing that I should do?